# Sync Windows Phone with Mac

Tags: 8.1, lumia, sync, phone-connector-mac

This question has been asked in this community couple of years ago, and Windows Phone 7 connector for Mac has been suggested as the answer. Now times have changed and this service is no longer operational. I am using Lumia 625 with Windows 8.1 as OS. How can I sync my Windows Phone with Mac OS?

Mac: OS X El Capitan
Phone: Lumia 625, Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Use an USB cable. Put in it your Mac and normally it'll work.

If You want to sync files, I should consider using OneDrive on your Phone and Go to http://onedrive.com/ on your Mac. If You want To do It completly Go to http://m.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-sync-app-mac-os-x-updated-support-windows-phone-81 and download the app.